# Deferred deep linking in React Native for android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

Please, share your expierience in implementing deferred deep linking in React Native for android.
I've set deep linking and it works good only if user has installed app. But if hasn't, it would be great to redirect them to Play market... And I can't figure it out how to implement such functionality.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Universal link not working if app is not installed on an iOS Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434221/universal-link-not-working-if-app-is-not-installed-on-an-ios-device)

Answer (score 0):

kindly add the following code in xcode and in android manifest to let your app know about your app's deep linked name, my apps deep link name is recreative

for xcode write it in AppDelegate.m

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

for android add it in src/main/AndroidManifest

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="recreative" 
              android:host="recreative"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

for more settings read this article
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/